# Problems to export function

Tags: javascript, cryptography, firefox-addon

I'm trying to use the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Lib](https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) on a add-on, but I have problems when I paste its code on a module.

I made a test project here:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/209559/latest/

The main function calls the functions that are describeds in the teste.js.

If I leave only this code on the teste.js

```
exports.generateKey = generateKey;
/***
 *  Function test (I know that I could not to generate a constant key)
 ***********************************************/
function generateKey(){
    return 123455;
}
```

The main function (on main.js) finds the function generateKey and shows the number 123455 in the console.

But when I add the code of the Stanford Lib, it stops to work and I get the follow error

> TypeError: t.generateKey is not a function

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crypto library [overrides](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/7a81296e3efd4756f5b441332f15b8f77061ccab/core/sjcl.js#L71-L73) your exports with their own exports:

```
if(typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports){
  module.exports = sjcl;
}
```

I cannot yet find where or if this is documented, but in each SDK module there is a `module` object, one property of which is `module.exports` which starts out as an alias to `exports`.

As a result the unmodified crypto library is already a loadable and overriding your previous additions to `exports` entirely.

I recommend not touching the crypto library source and use it as is (e.g. naming the library `sjcl.js` and using it like `require("./sjcl").encrypt(...)`) and defining your wrapper functions, such as `generateKey`, in `main.js` or an entirely new module.

Comment: Thank you!
I created another file (named _sjcl.js_) like you sugested.